# Identify maximum directory name and maximum timestamp in a backup directory

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that is from time to time backups a json file from an config folder:

> /var/app/v1/json/myfile.json
>
> /var/app/v2/json/myfile.json

And puts it in a directory created on the fly:

e.g. v1

> /var/backup/v1/20180810/myfile.json
>
> /var/backup/v1/20180809/myfile.json
>
> /var/backup/v1/20180808/myfile.json

e.g. v2

> /var/backup/v2/20180809/myfile.json
>
> /var/backup/v2/20180801/myfile.json

At some point when I need to restore, based on the version (v1, v2, v3) I need to identify the latest available backup for a given version.

e.g. For v1, I will need to identify: /var/backup/v1/20180810/myfile.json

e.g. For v2, I will need to identify: /var/backup/v2/20180809/myfile.json

e.g. For v3, I will need to identify latest one from previous version: /var/backup/v2/20180809/myfile.json

Can someone help and give me some guidance on how I can achieve this using bash script functions?

Thanks,
Cristi

Comment: Just move to `rdiff-backup`.

Comment: I don't understand v3. How is "latest one from previous version" different from v2?

Comment: If I need to restore v2, I have an existing v2 and I need to identify latest timestamp inside v2.

Comment: If I need to restore v3, I don't have any v3 and I need to fallback to previous version, which is v2. Now as above, same logic is applied and I need to identify latest timestamp from within v2 directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir=/var/backup/v1 or /var/backup/v2
find "$dir" -type f -maxdepth 2 -regextype sed \
    -regex ".*/[0-9]\{8\}/myfile.json" |
sort |
tail -n1
```

First we find all the files inside the directory matching the structure you described, so inside the `/var/backup/v1` directory at most 1 directory down find a file in a folder named with 8 numbers with exactly the name `myfile.json`.
No we can use, that the folder timestamp is `YYYYMMDD` and it's the same and the first 3 levels must be the same - we can just sort it. As all the paths are the same except for the directory name, we will receive folders sorted using the numbers/timestamp of the folders inside. Then we just list the latest file by printing the last line.

So the filter function may look like this:

```
find_maximum_file() {
    local dir file
    dir="$1"
    file="$2"
    find "$dir" -type f -maxdepth 2 -regextype sed \
        -regex ".*/[0-9]\{8\}/$file" |
    sort |
    tail -n1 |
}
```

and we can use it like this:

```
find_maximum_file /var/backup/v1 myfile.json
```

or like this:

```
find_maximum_file /var/backup/v2 myfile.json
```

Online code available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/ScuAFR).